Inequality based problem.
How to solve the following problem in general pattern?
If $a=√5-√4, b=√7-√6, c= √13-√12$
then :
(A) $a < b$
(B) $b > c$
(C) $b < c$
(D) $a < c$
My Attempt : $a = \sqrt(5) - \sqrt(4) = 2.236-2= 0.236, b = \sqrt(7) - \sqrt(6) = 2.646 - 2.449 = 0.197, c = \sqrt(13) - \sqrt(12) = 3.606 -- 3.464 = 0.142$. Clearly option (B) is correct. My question is that how to solve this problem by more general method and alternative approach.

Hint:  show that the function $f(x)=\sqrt {x+1}-\sqrt x$ is strictly decreasing in the relevant range.

Hint: Consider $f(n) = \sqrt{n+1}- \sqrt{n} = \dfrac1{ \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$, an obviously decreasing function...

For $~0 \leq s < r:$
$$\sqrt{r} - \sqrt{s}$$
$$= \sqrt{r} - \sqrt{s} \times \frac{\sqrt{r} + \sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{r} + \sqrt{s}}$$
$$=\frac{r - s}{\sqrt{r} + \sqrt{s}}.$$
